# Do I need statd RPC ? Before disabling it, is there a way to check if it is a dependency?

Tags: debian-squeeze

I read the man page, and I think I don't need this. However, I am unsure and wanted to ask more information about it before disabling it. What is it? Before I disable this, is there a way to check to see if there is a dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can check if it has dependencies by doing a simulate on apt:

```
 apt-get -s remove package
```

If there are no other packages to remove it is safe. If you want to delete the package configuration files, make sure you use the --purge flag too.

```
apt-get remove --purge portmap
```

Answer (score 4):

up to my knowledge it's part of NFS server. if you dont use it - it should be safe to remove it.